# Vote on tag synonyms!

Tags: discussion, tags

We have some [tag synonym suggestions](https://academia.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms) that have not been voted on, despite being quite old. I'd like to suggest people visit the [tag synonym page](https://academia.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms) and vote on existing suggestions:

[image]

Click on the links of the left column (freehand circle!) to go to the voting page.

---

This should help people submit more tag synonyms in turn, which will improve our tagging system and the overall experience on the site (especially searching by tags)!

Comment: Can you explain the voting process a little more. I can only vote for the two publications synonyms. Presumably I cannot vote for jobs because I proposed it, but I don't see the vote count. I would be surprised if I didn't have a total answer score of 5 in plagiarism, writing, and cv. Am I missing something?

Comment: For looking for tag synonyms, you might find helpful: http://stared.github.io/tagoverflow/ (just beware that is work in progress; or well... write me if you need something, PM or with a GitHub issue).

Answer (score 5):

To use this question as a discussion on the proposed synonyms, the [writing](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/writing) --> [scientific-writing](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/scientific-writing) one doesn't seem like a good idea to me, as not all academic writing is scientific writing; from my understanding of the term "sciences", there are many academic fields outside of the sciences. Not sure if that's how the tag is used, but from simply a semantic standpoint I'm not a huge fan of this.

Comment: I understand your point of view, but on this one I think we should take a pragmatic approach. All the writing questions we have are scientific writing questions, as far as I can see. It makes no sense to have two tags with the same exact scope.

Comment: @F'x Makes sense. Do you object to moving the other direction, though? Having [tag:scientific-writing] --> [tag:writing]?

Comment: No, I don't. Let´s go with the more generic of the two.

Comment: @F'x or eykanal The synonym was created a while back, but the scientific-writing questions never got re-tagged. Can you hit them with your re-tag diamond mod hammer?

Comment: @StrongBad [Looks like F'x took care of it](http://academia.stackexchange.com/tags/writing/synonyms).

Comment: @eykanal are you sure? For example, this [question](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/12190/is-it-bad-style-if-a-section-has-exactly-one-subsection) only has the [tag:scientific-writing].

Comment: @StrongBad - Not anymore it doesn't! (You were right, I just performed the merge so we should be good now.)

Comment: @eykanal thanks. It might be better to delete this answer now just to keep the question up to date.

Answer (score 2):

To follow up on eykanal's post with another suggested synonym. There is a suggestion to equate [bibliometrics](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bibliometrics) and [h-index](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/h-index). This is a bit like equating chemistry with oxygen. Bibliometrics is a research field and the h-index is just one parameter used in bibliometrics. We then would need to equate also citation index and impact factor with bibliometrics. Hence, I don't think this synonym is very constructive.

Comment: Yet, h-index is so small that it is hardly a useful tag... Looking at its questions, they would be better tagged with bibliometrics

Comment: I don't think we have a citation index tag yet. As for making "impact factor" a synonym also, I think it is reasonable given that there really is no single definition of impact factor and the different measures of impact factor are just bibliometrics.

Comment: I can see your points, but for me bibliometrics is a wide field beyond a few indices. I guess it might be possible to split the term in the future if need be.

Answer (score 2):

It appears to me that [references](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/references) and [reference-request](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reference-request) have a split personality. In my opinion the questions should either be [recommendation-letter](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/recommendation-letter) or [citations](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/citations). Should we systematically re-tag the questions and then make [references](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/references) and [reference-request](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reference-request) be synonyms for [citations](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/citations) or [recommendation-letter](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/recommendation-letter), and if so, which one?

Comment: Dual-purpose tags are not helpful, as you've pointed out. I like the idea of retagging. I don't have a good feel for which one references should be a synonym for. My feeling is that it should go for "citations" rather than "recommendation letters," since I suspect that is the more common academic usage.

Comment: [tag:references] are citations, [see my proposal](http://meta.academia.stackexchange.com/a/864/49).

Comment: [tag:reference-request] is _wildly_ misused on this site. This tag is on many SE sites and mean _asking to give a paper backing particular claim_ (see e.g. http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/28/academic-salaries-at-european-universities). In other cases we should retag [tag:recommendation-letter].

Answer (score 1):

I made a proposal for [ms](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ms) to be a synonym of [masters](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/masters) back when there were a few questions tagged [ms](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ms). They have all been retagged, but the synonym has not been created. Do we want the synonym?

Comment: It's done, could you delete it?

Comment: @PiotrMigdal the questions have been re-tagged for a while but the synonym has not been created.

Answer (score 1):

I made a proposal for [phd-thesis](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/phd-thesis) to be a synonym of [thesis](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/thesis) back when there were a few questions tagged [phd-thesis](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/phd-thesis). They have all been retagged, but the synonym has not been created. Do we want the synonym?

Comment: Is it done? I don't see any questions under [tag:phd-thesis]...

Comment: @PiotrMigdal All the questions have been re-tagged, but the synonym has not been created. The community needs to vote for it, or the mods need to hit it with a hammer. The purpose of this question is to allow below without enough rep in the respective tags to help guide the mods.

Answer (score 0):

[references](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/references) -> [citations](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/citations)

(Or the other way. I don't have a strong feeling which name is better. Just [citations](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/citations) is more popular.)

Comment: The references tag runs into the problem of recommendation letter, so I think making it the synonym is the way to go with the citations tag as the master. That said we would need to go through all the questions and retag the ones related to reference letters.

Answer (score -2):

I made a proposal for [phd-committee](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/phd-committee) to be a synonym of [advisor](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/advisor) back when there were a few questions tagged [phd-committee](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/phd-committee). They have all been retagged, but the synonym has not been created. Do we want the synonym?

Comment: I don't see why two tags should be related.

Comment: @PiotrMigdal because at the time all the questions tagged phd-committee were talking about phd advisors. Potentially there is a difference, but I am not sure what it is. Maybe you could propose a tag wiki entry that would make it clear why they are different.

Comment: I know "phd committee" as "PhD thesis defense committee" (advisor is there, but it is a very different animal than just advisor). I hope that retagged questions were NOT specifically related to it.

Answer (score -3):

I made a proposal for [mba](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mba) to be a synonym of [masters](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/masters) back when there were a few questions tagged [mba](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mba). They have all been retagged, but the synonym has not been created. Do we want the synonym?

Comment: From practical point of view, MBA is a a specific masters. I would prefer to keep them separate.

Comment: @PiotrMigdal yet you feel ms, which is a specific masters, should be a synonym of masters. What about MA?

Comment: Did I? (I now "ms" only for "Ms.", BTW.)

Comment: @PiotrMigdal MS stands for Masters of Science and MA stands for Masters of Art, just like MBA stands for Masters of Business Administration.

Comment: (I guessed.) Just I always see it always in the form MSc (albeit with various placements of `.` and ` `). Both MSc and MA are masters, the only difference is subject (and we have tags for subjects, if needed). Whereas, from my observation, MBA has different specifics (e.g. expensive, for business oriented people rather than a typical step in academic career, often taken not directly after Bachelor's (and less related to Bachelor's background), etc). Too bad it was retagged and I cannot even see whether the issues had a lot in common with [tag:masters] or not.