# Disambiguating reference-request tags

Tags: discussion

So I've embarked on something of a tag wiki editing project, and as I'm working through my list, I've hit `reference-request`. This appears to be used in two different cases, rather than just one:

1. Requests for citations, references or documents to support a question
2. Questions about asking a recommender for a letter of reference

These are clearly two very different types of questions. Thoughts on the best way to split the tag to make it more clear?

Comment: BTW: Good luck with tag wikis! :)

Comment: See http://meta.academia.stackexchange.com/questions/645/vote-on-tag-synonyms/678#678

Comment: Isn't there a less disruptive way for mods to do these retagging projects, so that old questions don't drive down new ones on the front page?

Comment: @ff524 No idea, but its done now.

Comment: @ff524 Mods can re-tag all question with a particular tag as something else without flooding the front page, but cannot (or at least I do not know how) mass re-tag a subset of a tag. Most sites try and do selective retagging slowly so as not to flood the front page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Stack Exchange sites [reference-request](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reference-request) has the first meaning. I think that it should have the same meaning on Academia.SE.

See:

- https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/reference-request
- https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reference-request

So for reference letters, why not [reference-letters](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reference-letters)?

Comment: Seems reasonable to me. Once I'm back in a place with decent internet, I'll retag and label.

Comment: Or alternatively: [tag:recommendation-letters]?

Answer (score 1):

As I have said [before](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/645/vote-on-tag-synonyms/678#678) I agree that [reference-request](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reference-request) and [references](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/references) have split personalities and needs to be cleaned up. When I looked in the past the questions pretty cleanly fell into [recommendation-letter](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/recommendation-letter) and [citations](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/citations).

Despite the meaning of [reference-request](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reference-request) on other SE sites, I think we should either blacklist [reference-request](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reference-request) and [references](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/references) (which is pretty extreme or make them synonyms of either [recommendation-letter](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/recommendation-letter) and [citations](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/citations) since it is ambiguous here. Being a synonym of [citations](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/citations) would be more consistent with other SE sites, but I am not sure that is how we use it now. Maybe doing a count of the question before re tagging them would be useful to get a feel for how the tag is being used.

Comment: I think I'd be up for blacklisting - having retagged everything to date, it's a pretty heavy split, with most of the posts being more suitable for recommendation-letter. I added a definition as well, but as far as anyone reads it...